# need help writing subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm using a health database and trying to display patients who have visited the health facility more than two times. The basic query I have so far is

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM PATIENT
```

I know I have to use a subquery in there somehow, but I don't know if I need to use Count or any other operators to find patients visiting more than two times.

[image: These are my tables and relationships between them]

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join with visit and count for distinct(VisitDate)  filtering using having  for the count > 1

```
  SELECT FirstName, LastName , count(distinct VisitDate)
  FROM PATIENT 
  inner join  VISIT on VISIT.patientID = PATIENT.PatientID 
  group by FirstName, LastName 
  having count(distinct VisitDate) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `count` and `having` clause for comparison

```
  SELECT P.FirstName, P.LastName,COUNT(V.VisitID) as numberOfVisit
    FROM VISIT V
    JOIN PATIENT P ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
    GROUP BY V.PatientID, P.FirstName, P.LastName
    HAVING COUNT(V.VisitID) > 2
```

By using sub query you can also get same result but no need that 1st query is more appropriate

```
select * from (
        SELECT P.FirstName, P.LastName,COUNT(V.VisitID) as numberOfVisit
        FROM VISIT V
        JOIN PATIENT P ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
        GROUP BY V.PatientID, P.FirstName, P.LastName
) as T where T.numberOfVisit>2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select x.FirstName,x.LastName from (
     SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName,count(*) n
     FROM PATIENTa,visit b
          where a.patientid = b.patientid 
     group by a.FirstName, a.LastName having count(*) > 2
) x
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.